# Meteor js: saving collection on client

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, client-side

I have a products collection and I want to allow users to add multiple images to them.

The catch is I want images to upload instantly but because the product isnt saved yet the images can't be embedded or joined by foreign key.

Is it possible to store the images clientside then after the product gets saved. I add the images to the product database?

How should I solve this?
Thanks

```
var imageStore = new FS.Store.GridFS("images");

Images = new FS.Collection("images", {
  stores: [
    new FS.Store.FileSystem("original")
  ],
  filter: {allow: {contentTypes: ['image/*']}}
});
```

Comment: almost a year ago i was struggling like you to have FSCollection working on my app, so i make [this example repo](https://github.com/Ethaan/simple-uploadFS) hope it works for you

Answer (score 0):

In Meteor, images will upload "instantly" due to the "db everywhere" paradigm,ie they will be stored optimistically in the MiniMongo client-side db and then sent to the server.  If they are rejected by the server, an error should be generated re the reason for the rejection (in your server logs.)

For code samples of how to upload files using CollectionFS, take a look at  [these code samples at the CollectionFS wiki](https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS/wiki).

[This one](https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS/wiki/Insert-One-or-More-Files-From-File-Input), for example, seems to be what you are looking for:

```js
Template.myForm.events({
    'change .myFileInput': function(event, template) {
        FS.Utility.eachFile(event, function(file) {
        Images.insert(file, function (err, fileObj) {
        //If !err, we have inserted new doc with ID fileObj._id, and
        //kicked off the data upload using HTTP
      });
    });
  }
});
```

Once the files are have been stored in the client db, you should be able to display them instantly, such as using [this method](https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS/wiki/Display-an-Uploaded-Image).

If this doesn't help, please provide a link to a repo or more details re. the issue, such as any errors that are being generated, esp server-side errors.

Comment: Hey you misunderstood the Q. I can get the images to upload fine and they will display instantly. But the issue is that I want to embed the images collection inside of the product collection. Similar to a foreign key association in sql type databases. 
Now this is a problem because since all the images upload instantly they will be uploaded before the product is persisted in the database so the images wouldn't know to whom they belong. I was asking if there is a way that I could hold the image collection in the minimongo client db up until the product gets submitted. Then I could join them.

Comment: Oh, in that case, it seems you might be looking for a collection hook, where you create the association before the insert.  See https://atmospherejs.com/matb33/collection-hooks